# Calling a parent class method from a derived derived class

Tags: c#

I have this:

```
public class Base {
   public virtual void Connect()
   {
      // do stuff
   }
}

public class Derived1 : Base {
   public override void Connect()
   {
       base.Connect();
      // do other stuff
   }
}

public class Derived2 : Derived {
   public override void Connect()
   {
      base.Connect() // Here I want to call Base::Connect(), not Derived::Connect()
   }
}
```

Is there a way I can call Base::Connect from Derived2, because I want to skip the "do other stuff" part from Derived1::Connect() ?

edit: Its mandatory that I derived from Derived1.

Comment: I never tried to do something like this, but have you tried `base.base.Connect()`?

Comment: Can you change `Base` or `Derived1`?

Comment: @Nolonar: That won't work.

Comment: I can change Derived1 and if there is no other way possible Base

Comment: From Mr. Lippert's stackoverflow post on this topic (AKA horse's mouth): http://stackoverflow.com/a/2327821/426422

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call base.base.method()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323401/how-to-call-base-base-method)

Comment: Why not just have Derived2 extend Base?  It doesn't seem to naturally extend Derived1 here.  If there is a lot of common code, you might need an abstract BaseDerived that both Derived1 and Derived2 extend.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call a second-level base class method like base.base.GetHashCode()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006530/how-to-call-a-second-level-base-class-method-like-base-base-gethashcode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo can try splitting Connect into two functions and call `DoConnect` from all derived classes, where it is needed:

```
public class Base {
   public virtual void Connect()
   {
      DoConnect();
   }

   protected void DoConnect()
   {
      // do stuff
   }
}

...

public class Derived2 : Derived1 {
   public override void Connect()
   {
      DoConnect();
      ...
   }
}
```

If you cant update the base class, you can do this splitting at `Derived1`

```
public class Derived1 : Base {
   public virtual void Connect()
   {
      DoConnect();
   }

   protected void DoConnect()
   {
      base.Connect();
   }
}
```

Comment: I know the code is bad, but because I cannot change much of it, your solution is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

C# dose not provide direct way to call `base.base.method()` you need first to change your design.
kindly check this answer [why-c-sharp-doesnt-support-base-base](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7648949/7648910)

So you need to change your design little to make little trick or workaround.

1. Define a new method in your class `Derived1` that it's only work is to call `base.Connect()`
2. Then in your class `Derived2()` define your `Connect()` that 'll simply call the previous function defined in the previous step.

check this example:

```
public class Base {
    public virtual void Connect() {
        // do stuff
    }
}

public class Derived1: Base {
    public override void Connect() {
        base.Connect();
        // do other stuff
    }
    public void CallBaseConnnect() {
        //here make only one call to base.Connect(). 
        //that's how class Derived1 'll provide you away to call base.Connect().
        base.Connect();
    }
}

public class Derived2: Derived {
    public override void Connect() {
        //here just make a call to CallBaseConnnect() in base class Derived1
        //that 'll equivalent to base.base.Connect.
        base.CallBaseConnnect();
    }
}
```